# How can I get Bearer Token using Username and Password form AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm writing REST API which needs Bearer token of the user in Azure AD B2C.I've user credentials(Username and Password) with me.

How can I get the Bearer Token?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Azure AD B2C doesn't support Resource Owner Password Credentials flow currently , you could vote for this feature in [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/13817784-add-support-for-resource-owner-password-credential) .

Comment: How can I solve this? Are there any other possibilities to solve this?

Comment: No , you may pay attention to above feedback and waiting for officially support .